# Can I perform reviews from the mobile app?

Tags: feature-request, review, ios-app, review-audits

Went on mobile, I have more free moments here and there – as compared with when I'm at my desk. I could use the time to moderate and perform reviews.

Maybe this could be limited to a subset of reviews, initially, and the quality of feedback compared with desktop users.  This would help  determine suitability of the mobile context as an environment for reviews.